# Java: why java can't automatically "finalize" local variables in enclosing scope of lambda expression?

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, final

I understand this as a standard part of functional programming.. my question is to why the compiler cannot automatically declare a copy of the variable as final just before the lambda statement begins?

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Example
{
  public static void main( String args[] )
  {
    int i = 5;
    i = 6;
    IntStream.range(0, 10).mapToLong( j-> i * j ).sum();
  }


}
```

fails... with "Local variable i defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final" whereas it seems the compiler should be smart enough to do something like this

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Example
{
  public static void main( String args[] )
  {
    int i = 5;
    i = 6;
    final int _i = i;
    IntStream.range(0, 10).mapToLong( j-> _i * j ).sum();
  }


}
```

the compiler could enforce that the finalized variable is never modified by the lambda function

Comment: It could; it would just make the code harder to reason about.

Comment: Would make it harder to use and understand in multithreaded scenarios (that also benefit from finals).

Comment: @AdamKotwasinski how does multi-threading change anything? Im not proposing that the lambda function be able to modify variables in its parent scope

Comment: @crow only assigning a variable once makes it easier to reason about code (as in actual functional languages like Haskell). And if you only assign it once, it's effectively final (or maybe actually final), and so you don't need copies to use it in the lambda.

Comment: @AndyTurner true it does seem to be an indication that some refactoring is called for in the form of method extraction ... I'm working on some code where the variable is declared.. then a for loop is iterated through which assigns the variables and then the lambda expression is called for.. seems like the for loop should be extracted into a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the compiler *would* actually do it if your variable `i` were effectively final.

```
  public static void main( String args[] )
  {
    int i = 5;
    IntStream.range(0, 10).mapToLong( j-> i * j ).sum();
  }
```

However with the second assignment `i = 6;` you're making it not "effectively final", you're indicating that you actually want it to be mutable.

So why in this case should the compiler make a final copy of your variable despite you signalling that you want it to be mutable?

Comment: the compiler should know that variable isn't modified after the lambda expression in the enclosing scope nor is modified within the lambda expression and should therefore generate the necessary byte codes such that my workaround of adding "final int _a = a;" just before the lambda expression isn't necessary. boiler plate code sucks and it has been the direction of recent java versions to make it less necessary to use verbose and boilerplate constructs like that

Answer (score 0):

But what if the lambda were passed somewhere which used it asynchronously (i.e. it can run after the current function ends), and you modify the variable `i` in the function scope *after* the creation of the lambda?

```
int i = 5;
i = 6;
useLambdaAsynchronously( j-> i * j );
i = 7;
```

The lambda would still have captured a value of 6 for `i`, but `i` (which is supposed to be the same variable, because you have only declared one `i`) now has the value of 7 in another scope. This is inconsistent, as the programmer should expect that a single variable has a single value at a time. If the lambda is run later, it will still use the value of 6 for `i` even though 7 has already been assigned to `i` previously.

To avoid this problem, the compiler would need to ensure that the variable is not assigned in the lambda *and* the variable is not assigned in the original function scope after the creation of the lambda. But that would lead to the situation where an assignment earlier in a function is allowed but later in the same function is disallowed (just because it has been captured by a lambda), which may also be surprising to the programmer. For simplicity, Java just disallows assignments anywhere.